# Unable to use Windows Update

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, windows-update

Updates fail, errors I get:

Error details: Code 643, Code 80070026, Code 800700C1

Here are the updates I try to install:

- KB2518870
- KB2572078
- KB2633870
- KB2656351
- KB2570947
- KB2468871
- KB2533523

I tried googling for these errors but haven't found any certain answers. I thought perhaps the experts here in superuser might be of help.

Comment: Can you install just one of those updates?

Answer (score 1):

According to a [post here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/cannot-install-2-important-updates-unknown-errors/68698317-526c-4a00-ba9a-e6995a05cae9) you might want to try turning off your anti-virus, and performing a clean boot (i.e. disable all programs and all non-Microsoft services at boot).

Comment: Nope :( that didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following three commands from an elevated command prompt:

```
net stop wuauserv
rmdir /s %windir%\SoftwareDistribution\WUredir
net start wuauserv
```

You can also do the same thing from the services control panel and by deleting (or renaming) the directory from Explorer.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help.

Comment: Try deleting the entire SoftwareDistribution folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might try, after deleting the SoftwareDistribution, to install those updates manually via command line. 
Two ways:

- with wuauclt (built-in, but i dont know how to select a specific update. if it is even possible?)
- with [wuinstall](http://wuinstall.com) (third party tool, but it uses the windows update api)

for example the command for installing the first mentioned update:

```
wuinstall.exe /install /match KB2518870
```

if both ways are still not working, you might update your windows update :)